# 2 dynamic size divs + float:left

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the bad title.

So I have 2 divs both with `float:left` property inside a container with fixed size. Each div can have optional size. Problem is if I fill div2 with a lot of text it goes below div1, but they should be next to each other. I want div2 just become smaller, not go below div1.

Check example on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5h5H/1/):

Comment: you used some kind of hack when posting *fiddle* link wihout **actual** code :)

Comment: won't `float:left` count as code

Comment: what ie version you have to support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
.div2 {
    float: none; /* default value */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w5h5H/6/)

Comment: Works, but the only problem I see is that if he needs to add another div next to div2 for some reason, it will automatically be shunted down to the next line.

If he sets a max-width div2 remains dynamic in size, yet he can adjust it if he needs to add an element directly to the right of it while keeping everything in line.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to nix the floats and use `display:table-cell` instead:

```
.div1 {
    border:1px solid red;
    display:table-cell;
}
.div2 {
    border:1px solid blue;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/w5h5H/3/)**

Comment: The problem with table-cell is you get these 3px margins that will sometimes render or not render in broswers, creating a problem with positioning.  Same problem with disply:inline-block.   I refuse to use table-cell or inline-block on my sites because of it.

Answer (score 0):

Set a max-width for div2.   Since you set no size for div2, when the length of text hits the edge of its parent element it drops down the next line.  max-width will allow it to be dynamic in size until it hits the limit.

```
.div2 { max-width: 250px; }
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/w5h5H/7/)

Comment: Problem is, div1 has also optional size, if I set fixed size of div2 and div1 gets bigger, it will also fall down.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to keep their sizes optional?  You really should define widths to cut down on headaches like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both div should be of

1. Equal hight
2. Always on left and right

then use

```
.div1 {       
    border:1px solid red;
    display: table-cell;
}

.div2 {        
    border:1px solid blue;
    display:  table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w5h5H/8/

Answer (score 0):

set a `max-width` on both divs as a percentage. Heres a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w5h5H/10/

The percentages may need adjusting down a little to allow for any margins or borders you have.